# Complex inner joins in Django

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to get this query to work for a couple of hours now and I would love some help since I'm still new to Django.

I have these models (simplified)

```
class Job(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    active = models.BooleanField()

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class State(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.ForeignKey(State)

class Worker(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    addresses = models.ManyToManyField(Address)

class Address(models.Model):
    address_field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)
```

I want to select all the distinct and active Jobs on all the Countries which my Worker has an Address on. My view has this code:

```
def get(self, request):
    worker = Worker.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    full_query = Q(active=True)
    # my problem is here, since it is a ManyToMany Relationship
    full_query &= Q(country__id__in=worker.addresses ??????)
    jobs = Job.objects.filter(full_query)
```

I think this will work getting all the worker's addresses in a for loop and saving the country id in a list and doing

```
 country_ids = []
 for address in worker.addresses:
     country_ids.append(address.city.state.country.id)
 Q(country__id__in=[country_ids])
```

But I think Django has a more elegant way of doing this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
jobs = Job.objects.filter(active=True).filter(country__state__city__address__in=worker.addresses.all())
```

Comment: you are a genius, sir. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries. Not a genius, just experienced with Django querysets ;).